# PHP detect and remove unnecessary cent of price

Tags: php

For invoicing I want to determine if my total amount has an unnecessary cent. e.g. $5.01 or $5.51. If it detects the cent then I run an if statement to remove the cent: minus 0.01 
eg.
Change `30.51` to `0.01` and give a warning message

and also
`30.51` to `0.51`

and also
`30.51` to `1`

Both come from a POST, so they are both **PHP strings**.

but no worries - i got it to work now thanks to dmayo

```
$pieces = explode(".", $TotalAmt);
echo "<br>p1:".$pieces[1]; // piece2
$p1 = $pieces[1];
$spl1 = str_split($p1);
$TAmttmp = 0; 
//echo "<br>sp11:".$spl1; // error convert array to string
$TAmttmp = $spl1[0];
echo "<br>TAmttmp: with useless cent".$TAmttmp;
echo "<br>IT:".$IT;
if ($TAmttmp == 0.01) //so if there is 1 cent subtract the useless cent.
$TAmt = $TAmt - 0.01;
echo "<br>TAmt: with useless cent".$TAmt;
echo "<br>TAmt: without useless cent".$TAmt;
```

Comment: Hello on SO. What are you trying?

Comment: What are the logics behind these conversions?

Comment: For invoicing I want to determine if my total amount has an unnecessary cent. e.g. $5.01 or $5.51. If it detects the cent then I run an if statement to remove the cent: minus 0.01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Gumbo is right, we need to know the logic behind your conversions to provide a precise answer.

You could do an explode:

```
$var = explode('.',$_POST['val']);
$digits = $var[1]; // this will give you the digits after the decimal point
```

Now you can do what you need based on your logic.

You could also you use a `substr()` where you find the decimal point (is it always three places from the right?) and then grab the substring.

Not sure which would be more efficient.

Comment: Ja thanks I liked the explode idea, i tried it and it gave me converting array to to string error when I conveted the last digit to a number, but then i finally figured it out:

Comment: $pieces = explode(".", $TotalAmt); <br/>   
//echo "<br>p0:".$pieces[0]; // piece1<br/>
echo "<br>p1:".$pieces[1]; // piece2<br/>
$p1 = $pieces[1];<br/>
$spl1 = str_split($p1);<br/>
$TAmttmp = 0;<br/>
//echo "<br>sp11:".$spl1; // error convert array to string <br/>
$TAmttmp = $spl1[0];<br/>
<br/>

echo "<br>TAmttmp: with useless cent".$TAmttmp;<br/>
echo "<br>IT:".$IT;<br/>

if ($TAmttmp  == 0.01) //so if there is 1 cent subtract the useless cent.<br/>
$TAmt = $TAmt - 0.01;<br/>
echo "<br>TAmt: with useless cent".$TAmt;<br/>
echo "<br>TAmt: without useless cent".$TAmt;

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what you want, but perhaps that helps:

```
$nr = "30.51";

echo round($nr - floor($nr), 2); // 0.51    
echo round(($nr * 10 - floor($nr * 10)) / 10, 2); // 0.01    
echo round(($nr * 10 - floor($nr * 10)) * 10); // 1
```